# Escape brackets in a regex with alternation

Tags: regex, escaping, brackets, alternation

I am trying to write a Reg Expression to match any word from a list of words but am having trouble with words with brackets.

This is the reg expression I have so far:

```
^\b(?:Civil Services|Assets Management|Engineering Works (EW)|EW Maintenance|Ferry|Road Maintenance|Infrastructure Planning (IP)|Project Management Office (PMO)|Resource Recovery (RR)|Waste)\b$
```

Words with brackets such as Civil Services are matched but not words with brackets such as Engineering Works (EW).

I have tried single escaping with \ and double escaping (\) but neither option seems to return a match when testing words with brackets in them.

How can I also match words with brackets?

Comment: Show a [mcve].  Which language are you using?

Comment: At the moment I am just testing on https://regex101.com/ 

The word list above is just an example but I am intending to use it in a product called Adaxes and I want to perform an action based on a list of departments. 

If AD Department Matches regexp (...) then create mailbox.

The syntax may differ slightly but just hoping to get a bit of an idea of how I can escape brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\b` can't match a word boundary the way you want when it's preceded by a `)`. A [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is a word character adjacent to a non-word character or end-of-string. A word character is a letter, digit, or underscore; notably, `)` is not a word character. That means that `)\b` won't match a parenthesis followed by a space, nor a parenthesis at the end of the string.

The easiest fix is to remove the `\b`s. You don't actually need them since you've already got `^` and `$` anchors:

```regex
^(?:Orange|Banana|Apple \(Red\)| Apple \(Green\)|Plum|Mango)$
```

Alternatively, if you want to search in a larger string you could use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to look a non-word character or end-of-string. This is essentially what `\b` does except we only look ahead, not behind.

```regex
\b(?:Orange|Banana|Apple \(Red\)| Apple \(Green\)|Plum|Mango)(?=\W|$)
```

Comment: I don't know if the OP even wants this, but just use `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` in place of `\b` word boundaries.  This way, you can place them only once, outside of the alternation.